# How can I download all the Latex Packages to my ubuntu system?

Tags: latex

I installed LaTeX python package on my system and able to compile small latex files. How to install all the existing packages from CTAN to my computer automatically?

How other online Latex editors are able compile any kind of latex file? How are they getting the required packages ?

Any suggestions please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed the followig commands on ubuntu local machine

```
sudo apt-get install texlive texstudio # for latex 
sudo apt-get install texlive-full  # for full texlive packages
sudo apt-get install xzdec        # for tlmgr
```

Also for online installation you can do this

```
wget -O http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
chmod u+x /tmp/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
cd /tmp && tar zxvf install-tl-unx.tar.gz
./install-tl
```

This will install latex packages on your server